# Possible HD configuration for ESXi

Tags: hard-drive, esxi

I am planning on upgrading my ESXi host with a few new hard drives, and I was wondering if the following configuration might be ok or if you would suggest something different:

- Boot from USB stick
- 2x 1 TB WD Black in RAID 1 (for VMs)
- 2x 2 TB WD Red in RAID 1 (for general content and files, attached to the VMs that work as file servers)

How does this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like where you're going with this but if you're approaching this how I think you might be you're introducing some choke points you probably don't want:

Booting from USB: I've done this with a few things and this works nicely. ESXi isn't too much of a pain to reinstall if it fails but you will end up losing your config. At a minimum see about just having a second USB stick and routinely have it mirror the primary or routinely back up your config.

I'm assuming you're having two drives each to do mirroring for redundancy (RAID 1). Spanning would be a bad idea entirely for this as you'd lose everything the instant a single drive failed.

On a traditional system this separation of the OS and data files isn't a bad idea and you can still do this *virtually*; however, doing this with your physical infrastructure in my opinion isn't the most optimal use of your hardware. The config you're suggesting leaves you with 1 TB for your OS and 2TB for DATA for a total of 3 TB available and 3 unavailable out of your purchased capacity.

Consider a RAID 5 or 6 configuration. For this you will want to get disks all the same size. Assuming you go with all 2 TB you'll have a total usable capacity of 6 GB with RAID 5 and 4 GB with RAID 6. If you need to save some cash you could go with 1.5TB disks and have 4.5 TB @ RAID 5  or 3 TB @ RAID 6.

RAID 5 vs RAID 6:
There has been some recent debate over the two which I'll let you research the gritty details. If this is for a home lab or something not super-critical RAID 5 should be fine and you'll get more space to play with. If you're using this for a production business environment I'd go with RAID 6 and enjoy the added protection of the data.

In either scenario I'd still be performing backups on an external drive of at least the data itself (such as from your file share) and/or using a service like Carbonite or similar if that's an option for you so you can have something separate from main operation of the system itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for the great answer. It's good that you mentioned services like Carbonite, however, I don't think there is a way to use them from within ESXi right? I mean, I would have to disconnect the drives, connect them to a computer where Carbonite is installed and then backup.

Comment: Carbonite would be more like if you had a VM running Windows Server with the File Share there - you'd then use Carbonite to backup the files for that particular VM. There are similar services out there for various OSes so it'd be worth some research if you're considering it as an option.